# Why are some images' height/width undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, image

Im currently trying to scrape a website for its imagesizes. I am using a module called scraperjs, which helps me with that in general. Now im at the point where i get all the images with their attributes, but since some of them have no stated height/width, the returned value is "undefined". If they have a height/width attribute, it works like a charm. How can i, even without their measurements being stated in the attributes, get their height/width.
Thanks in advance, here is my code.

```
var scraperjs = require('scraperjs');
url = process.argv.slice(2)[0];

if (!url) {
console.log('Usage: node ImgSizeGetter.js <url>');
return;
}

/*
 Get all the Imagessizes in a page.
 */
scraperjs.StaticScraper
.create()
.onStatusCode(function (code) {
//console.log(code);
})
    .scrape(function ($) {
/*return all img tags from entered url*/
return $('img').map(function () {
    /*read the height and width attr of each img returned*/
    var height = $(this).attr('height'),
        width = $(this).attr('width'),
        size = height + "x" + width;
    console.log(size);
    /*return size for further handling*/
    return size;
}).get();
})
    .then(function (images) {
/*do stuff*/
})
.get(url);
```

Here is the paste out of my node command prompt after calling the module:

```
node ImgSizeGetter.js https://reddit.com
70x70
52x70
70x70
62x70
36x70
70x70
52x70
69x70
70x70
69x70
70x70
59x70
69x70
52x70
70x70
52x70
39x70
52x70
67x70
39x70
70x70
52x70
68x70
39x70
undefinedxundefined
```

Notice how the last sizing if undefinedxundefined and after looking in the htmlsourcecode it turns out this is the only  with no height/width attribute set.

Comment: If the `<img>` doesn't have "height" and "width" attributes, there won't be values. You're explicitly asking jQuery to fetch the values of the *attributes* instead of just directly looking at the *properties* of the DOM nodes. Switch `.attr()` to `.prop()`.

Comment: It is probably [**cheerio**](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) and not JQuery

Comment: @codtex OK well same deal if it's really an "implementation of core jQuery".

Comment: I tried your answer and it actually seems that it doesnt recognize the .prop function. Might be because its cheerio, like @codtex stated.

Comment: .prop didnt fix the problem sadly, i still get undefinedxundefined as a returnvalue.

Answer (score 0):

The last `<img>` tag on reddit's homepage does not explicitly have any height or width attribute. It's a one pixel by one pixel transparent image.

What `$().attr()` does is look for actually set attributes and not properties. Attributes are what is actually written in the HTML file, properties are attributes and browser defaults mixed. Properties can change over time (for example though scripts) while attributes stay the same.

If you want to get the actual height and width of images use jQueries `$().prop("height")` and `$().prop("width")` function.

In your code this would look like this:

```
return $('img').map(function () {
    /*read the height and width prop of each img returned*/
    var height = $(this).prop('height'),
        width = $(this).prop('width'),
        size = height + "x" + width;
    console.log(size);
    /*return size for further handling*/
    return size;
}).get();
```

This returns the following:

```
0: "70x70"
1: "52x70"
2: "70x70"
3: "70x70"
4: "70x70"
5: "62x70"
6: "36x70"
7: "52x70"
8: "69x70"
9: "70x70"
10: "52x70"
11: "69x70"
12: "70x70"
13: "39x70"
14: "70x70"
15: "67x70"
16: "69x70"
17: "52x70"
18: "70x70"
19: "39x70"
20: "52x70"
21: "39x70"
22: "70x70"
23: "52x70"
24: "1x1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, totally makes sense! After trying your codeexample i come up with an error like this:
    TypeError: $(...).prop is not a function.

This might actually be due to the fact that its cheerio and not JQuery (stated by another answer above)

Comment: Hm, yeah, that might be a thing, you tagged it as jQuery, that's why I answered it for jQuery ^^

Comment: Seems like cheerio is basically core jQuery, the scraperjs framework has both listed as dependencies on their git, so it actually should be possible right?

Comment: Cheerio lists .prop() as a viable method: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#prop-name-value-

Comment: Indeed. If it only recieves a jQuery, .prop should be possible tho. Also why would .attr work, but .prop not. Im lost.

Comment: Ok then it might be my code, ill look into it. Thanks for helping me out so far.

Comment: Ok turns out scraperjs used an outdated version of cheerio which didnt support the .prop yet. After updating cheerio to the newest version, the prop function is called correctly and works. Only thing is i still get undefinedxundefined. Any idea why?

Comment: No, but as I said I didn't test it with cheerio or scraperjs